# How to refresh modal body when submit Ajax Post?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

Im submitting ajax request using **Bootstrap Modal** when i submit i want refresh modal body. it means what i have saved from my form im showing my modal body i want show that row in table. when i use this that table got hide not refreshing anything rong ?

```
 $('#uploadform').submit(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
        formData.append('task_id','{{$task->id}}');
        formData.append('title',$('#title').val());

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{{url('/uploadTask')}}',
            data:formData,
            success:function(data){

                $("#images-table").replaceWith($('#images-table', $(data)));

                $("#some_form")[0].reset();

            },
            error:function (data) {
                alert('error');
            },
            async:false,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
        });
    });
```

Comment: **$("#images-table").html($("#images-table").html());** Why you are using this?

Comment: its a table id i want refresh that table data after submit this form

Comment: check question .... that line

Answer (score 1):

You can simply refresh the Modal html by putting some new html into it like:

```
success:function(data){
    // here data contains the response for your ajax call
    var newHTML = data;
    $("#images-table").html(newHTML);  // This will put new html and remove old
}
```